# jQuery disable input function prevents selected option from loading

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am having a weird problem and I can't understand what exactly is causing it.
When one particular option in a select is selected, a separate input should be disabled. For all other options, the input should be enabled. I've got this to work. However, when the page is first loaded, this same option that disables the input is pre-selected using PHP: the option tag does contain `selected="selected"` but it doesn't load in the select drop-down. Instead, the first and empty option is loaded and because of the `required` attribute, a red border appears around the select drop-down. [image]

Here is the jQuery:

```
/* disable the 'subprice' input on the project form if vendorID is '1' */
$('#vendorID').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '1') {
        $('#subprice').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#subprice').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}).change();
```

Here is a fragment of the select drop-down (the generated HTML):

```
<select required name="vendorID" id="vendorID">
    <option value=""> - </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">.....</option>
    <option value="2">.....</option>
    <option value="3">.....</option>
```

This is the input which is being disabled/enabled:

```
<input type="text" name="subprice" id="subprice" value="" />
```

I am trying to rewrite an older function (plain JavaScript) into jQuery. The old function works perfectly. I simply want to modernise and simplify my code a bit.

```
function toggleSubprice() {
   var subprice = document.getElementById("subprice");
   var cheeseus = document.getElementById("cheeseus");
   updateToggle = cheeseus.selected ? subprice.disabled = true : subprice.disabled = false;
}
```

The "cheeseus" ID is added to the option using PHP:

```
<option value="<?php echo $vendor->vendorID; ?>"<?php echo (($vendor->vendorID == '1')? " id=\"cheeseus\"" : ""); ?>
```

EDIT: I have noticed something that has to do with the strange behaviour. When I choose **Inspect element** in Firefox, the empty option is shown as having the `selected="selected"` property, which is odd. The option that has a value of "1" should have it. And when I view the page source, **it does**. See the two extra screenshots attached.[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The code that works is as follows:

```
if($("#vendorID").length > 0) {
    toggleSubprice();
    $('#vendorID').on('change', toggleSubprice);
}
```

The above is inside `$(document).ready(function()`.

Outside that is the function itself:

```
function toggleSubprice() {
   var $vendorID = $('#vendorID');
   var $subrpice = $('#subprice');
   if($vendorID.val() == '1') {
      $subrpice.prop("disabled", true);
      console.log('subprice disabled');
   } else {
      $subrpice.prop("disabled", false);
      console.log('subprice enabled');
   }
```

}

Of course, the `console.log()` part is not necessary. I only added it to be able to monitor if the function executes because at some point it wasn't.

Pretty sure a more elegant solution exists, so if anyone wants to improve this, please do.